# how to know a wifi hotspot's detail info?

Tags: 7.5, wifi

i have a WP7.5 device which can connect to company network(a hotspot) using my domain account, i want to know the detail informations about this wifi, so i can set other devices properly to connect to the net.

like encryption types:
EAP-TLS
EAP-TTLS/MSCHAPv2
PEAPv0/EAP-MSCHAPv2
PEAPv1/EAP-GTC
EAP-SIM

how to know details?

Comment: Why not just ask your local friendly network administrator?

Comment: @RowlandShaw yes, of cource i can ask them, but i want to know more about my phone, DIY some times fun right?

Answer (score 4):

Under settings/WiFi you can long tap on a connection and select edit.

From here you can see:

- Encryption Type—shown in brackets next to the connection name e.g. AccessPoint1(WPA2)
- Your IP address
- Subnet mask
- Default gateway IP
- DNS server IP
- DNS suffix
- Your MAC address

Comment: Worth noting that you can only do this whilst connected to the WiFi connection in question

Comment: Yeah a bit of a shame. There doesn't seem to be an equivalent to the Android Wifi Analyzer app.